# Not able to return back to the app from ChromeCustomTabsBrowser

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, openid-connect, chrome-custom-tabs

I have implemented login using ChromeCustomTabsBrowser. After successful login, if app's Open Supported links setting is set to "Ask evety time" instead of "Open in this app", response is not getting back to the app and showing 404 screen as attached in screen.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586854/oidcclient2-closing-ibrowser-while-waiting-for-loginasync

Comment: already gone through that, IBrowserFallback is not available

Answer (score 0):

Interesting - looks like you are using an https scheme for redirects and here is how we'd like the technology to work:

- You are automatically deep linked back to your app when a login response is received over the https URL.

However, in practice I believe this is what happens:

- Almost all mobile browsers try to run an internet hosted web page instead

A claimed https scheme solution is very hard to achieve and rarely used in practice today - more of an aspiration than a reality? But I believe it would need to work like this:

- Capture the response on the internet web page which runs on your mobile device
- Then deep link back to the app

A similar approach is used by a [sample internet web page](https://web.authguidance-examples.com/mobile/postlogin.html) of mine - do a view source to see the logic

If it helps I have a demo Android sample that instead uses the more mainstream option of private URI schemes - though I may update it to claimed https schemes one of these days.

- [Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android)
- [Explanatory Articles](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/)

Even getting this form of Chrome Custom Tab based login working was a struggle, and my posts have some lessons learned that may be useful.

Comment: Yes. I am using https scheme for redirects. Its working perfect when Open Supported links setting is set to "Open in this app" but not working otherwise

Comment: I have checked your code my activity has same configs as your DeepLinkForwardingActivity.

Comment: I updated my answer with some more detail - an interesting topic - if you resolve the problem I'll be interested in your solution.

Comment: I have changed https scheme to use custom scheme and then got it working